# Spring cant find properties file in Tomcat classpath.

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, properties, classpath

I have Spring configured to look up a conf/database.properties file to load some configuration.
This works well outside Tomcat, and in Junit tests, but in Tomcat, it never load. Below the images of this problem.

***Configurations:***

[image: Configuration 1] 
***And:***

[image: Configuration 2]

***The properties file in project folder:***

[image: The file in folder]

***The parameters to run Tomcat inside Eclipse:***
[image: The run parameters]

***The temp0 Tomcat Folder, where is all the files being generated Ok:***
[image: Generated application in tomcat temp0 folder]

***The Tomcat error log:***

```
https://gist.github.com/4060538
```

Comment: Not sure why you are using * in the property placeholder configuration - surely you expect one any only one database.properties. Do you get a 'Failed to load resource' error if you remove the '*'?

Comment: I tried a lot of different manners. Removing it the same error occurs.

Comment: One more information: My spring.xml file is inside a jar library. The web app project contains the database.properties file will be referenced by the other library who needs this configuration in Classpath. It's not a problem this architecture right? Spring should load that right?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. I think I was using spring in the wrong way.

I changed the follow:

- In the library I'm importing/referencing, I removed the line where was importing database.properties file.
- I created a spring.xml in my main web app, where in this file I imported the database.properties file and the other app-context.xml files I need to reference.

I think Spring spring don't load properties file outside of the jar. You need to load properties file locally in you main application, and so, references another spring-context.xml files needed.